# Windows store app development - Windows 2012

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, windows-server-2012

I would like to develop Windows Store App using Windows Server 2012. Is it possible?
During installing VS 2013 some hint appeared: "windows store app development requires windows 8.1".

Answer (score 2):

Reading [the MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211384.aspx) it mentions the following

> You can't create an app by using Windows 7. In addition, developer licenses aren't available for Windows Server 2012, so you can't develop a Windows Store app on that operating system.

So no, you can not develop Store apps using Server 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can't develop Windows Store App using Windows Server 2012, because developer licenses aren't available for Windows Server 2012.

You can read more about it on MSDN: [Develop apps by using Visual Studio 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211384.aspx)